# UITextView keyboard dismissed by clicking UIAlertView OK button iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, uitextview, uialertview

Am working in messaging based iPhone app. In one of my UIViewController i am showing UITextView keyboard and am getting some alert messages from webservice.

When i show the alert messages in UIAlertView, UITextview keyboard is dismissing by clicking OK button from UIAlertView. I have tried to put becomeFirstResponder in UIAlertView delegate but, still keyboard dismissing. For your reference,

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   [messageTextView becomeFirstResponder]; // Here again I am giving becomeFirstResponder to my UITextView

   int alertMessageArrayCount = [alertMessageArray count];
    if (messageAlertView) 
    {
        if (messageAlertCount < alertMessageArrayCount)  // These codes to show my all messages in UIAlertView one by one..
        {
            messageAlertCount = messageAlertCount + 1;

            arrayObjectValue = arrayObjectValue + 1;

            NSString *alertMessage = [alertMessageArray objectAtIndex:arrayObjectValue];

            messageAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:alertMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [messageAlertView show];
            [messageAlertView release];
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help to solve this issue?

**EDIT :**

```
messageTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 5, 210, 30)];
messageTextView.delegate = self;
messageTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
messageTextView.clipsToBounds = NO;
messageTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
[self.view addSubView:messageTextView];
```

Comment: Am not using IBOutlet only programmatically using friend.

Comment: To dismiss a keyboard I think you should use [messageTextView resignFirstResponder];

Comment: @NULL am not looking to dismiss keyboard friend. I don't want to dismiss the keyboard while clicking OK button in UIAlertView. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

in your UIAlertView delegate method try like below insted of  [messageTextView becomeFirstResponder];

```
if([messageTextView resignFirstResponder]){
    [messageTextView becomeFirstResponder];
    }
```

Comment: It is not working friend. i don't know what is happening in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Write delegate of alertview "nil" instead of self.

```
 messageAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:alertMessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
```

Comment: but i want to show multiple uialertview's one by one after clicking "OK" button that is why i set delegate self friend.